# Matrix of chars (dynamically allocated 2D array) in c

Tags: c

What's wrong with this code?
I'm trying to put n lines from stdin into matrix of `chars **a`.
`**a` needs to be dynamically allocated.

Here's the code:

```
int main()
{

    char **a=NULL;
    int n;
    int i=1;
    int j=0;
    char c;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    getchar();

    a=malloc(n*sizeof(char*));

    while(n>0)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            c=getchar();

            if(c=='\n')
            {
                j++;
                break;
            }

            i++;
            a[j]=realloc(a,i*sizeof(char));
            a[j][i-2]=c;
            a[j][i-1]='\0';

        }

        i=1;
        n--;
    }


    printf("%s\n",a[0]); 

    free(a); 
}
```

Comment: Please explain this line `a[j]=realloc(a,i*sizeof(char));` in comparison to `a[j]=realloc(a[j],i*sizeof(char));`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I replaced that line of code with a[j]=realloc(a[j],i*sizeof(char)); and it works! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
a[j]=realloc(a,i*sizeof(char));
```

with

```
a[j]=realloc(a[j],i*sizeof(char));
```

in order to only realloc one of the sub arrays and not the whole array.
I recommend to also do the improvement recommended in the other answer, to init the subarrays, which also turns the first realloc into an alloc.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialising the array a.
Add `a[j] = NULL` as follows

```
int main()
{

    char **a=NULL;
    int n;
    int i=1;
    int j=0;
    char c;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    getchar();

    a=malloc(n*sizeof(char*));

    while(n>0)
    {
        a[j] = NULL;
        while(1)
        {
            c=getchar();

            if(c=='\n')
            {
                j++;
                break;
            }

            i++;
            a[j]=realloc(a[j],i*sizeof(char));
            a[j][i-2]=c;
            a[j][i-1]='\0';

        }

        i=1;
        n--;
    }


    printf("%s\n",a[0]); 

    free(a); 
}
```